# Kafka design question with duplicate events

Tags: apache-kafka, akka-cluster

I have this architecture with Kafka that I would like to figure what is the best way to solve it.

I have `two Kafka Producers` to avoid Single point of failure, that are subscribed each to a external service, and when this service send the callback, both are generating the exactly same event, and they are sending to same topic `Bla`.

Then I have a `consumer` subscribed to that Topic `Bla`, that consume the events duplicated.

Possible Solutions: Use some distributed clutter like Akka distributed data, to communicate producers, and only send one event.

Or make my consumer idempotent and being able to consume duplicated events without conflicts.

There's any other alternative to this?

Regards

Comment: Use a distributed lock around your producer send event

Comment: I read zookeeper can do that, I will read about it

Comment: Curator is a higher level library that can help, too.